# How do I parse a custom SQL query from a DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, sql, tableau-api

I'm pulling custom SQL queries from the Tableau metadata and trying to pull out only the schema & table names from the dataframe. I'm looking for something that will help me pull out only the text between "from" and "where", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install sql-metadata`

This allows you to select columns and tables from SQL queries

https://github.com/macbre/sql-metadata#readme